# Can i change price resource in layer navigation in collection.php

Tags: php, magento, filter, layered-navigation

**Update**

in layer navigation on left side in price filter i want to show price and count by SRP(Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price) in my database if user not logged in My SRP Price not save in Catalog_product_index_price but it stay in other database

(on other in my page will show srp if user not logged in except for layer navigation)

can I change  `'$this->_priceExpression = $table . '.min_price';'` to e.msrp 
in

```
 'function _preparePriceExpressionParameters' 

     from '\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Collection.php'
```

I get select form this function I saw 'e.msrp' but I can't use it but I can change .`min_price to max_price` final+price`and other price in $table` or `'price_index.???'`

**PS.**

```
$table = self::INDEX_TABLE_ALIAS; and price_index. = INDEX_TABLE_ALIAS 
but e = MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. I can't understand. So please update your question clearly.

Comment: I just update detail and sorry for my language